# How to import Langchain module in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, langchain

I am facing an issue with Lambda function. I want to import Langchain python module in AWS Lambda function. But I am facing issue with it. It shows following error :

- `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'orjson.orjson'"`

I am not using orjson package. But it still throws error. I tried to install langchain in Ubuntu environment inside Docker. After zipping the data in zip folder and uploading it to the Lambda Layers. But can't find the solution over internet.

I have also tried "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:609061237212:layer:langchain:6". It's public ARN of langchain module.

Can anyone tell me solution for this issue ?

I also tried to put the package folders inside "/python" folder. But it doesn't solve my error.